# How does sneak attack work with a fighter/rogue multi-class with an extra attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, sneak-attack

I have a level 12 rogue/fighter. Level 7 rogue with level 5 fighter. So I get the extra attack as the level 5 fighter. How does sneak attack work with that? Do I only get to apply it on one attack?

Situation is I am going to be a sniper using Sharpshooter. I have the assassin archetype to pick off enemies before we even enter combat. In combat I'm off in the distance while others are fighting up close, so I can snipe enemies from afar with the sneak attack bonus to hit harder. But with that 2nd attack, how do those modifiers work?

Comment: Related on [If I have extra attacks, when can I decide which one is a sneak attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117613/if-i-have-extra-attacks-when-can-i-decide-which-one-is-a-sneak-attack)

Comment: Enkryptor, is the edited version better? I am not asking opinions on a better build, more what mechanically could be done to improve it. That is diving into rules and synergy. I can remove the last part if needed to improve this overall.

Comment: NautArch, that question is somewhat similar, but it is asking when to assign the sneak attack damage. It does not necessarily explain whether or not you get the bonus twice. I might be misinterpreting it though.

Comment: It's just related :) but I'm unclear if you're asking how something works vs most effective sniper build. The latter is a different question and needs some qualifiers such as burst Nova damage or consistent damage.

Comment: I also am going to remove that last bit, as it really is an entirely different question that needs it's own submission. If you'd like to hop into [chat], we can help you narrow it down.

Comment: *"But with that 2nd attack, how do those modifiers work?"* — what modifiers do you mean?

Comment: @enkryptor I was meaning the sneak attack bonus. Not modifiers. As in if I attacked the 2nd attack would it have gotten the sneak attack bonus as well. Which the answer below explains that is not the case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### You can only sneak attack once per turn

The feature description says this explicitly:

> **Once per turn**, you can deal an extra Xd6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll.

### It still worth doing tho

It gives you 4d6 damage for the 7 level rogue, in addition to your two attacks as the 5th level fighter. That would be 2*(1d8+DEX) per attack for longbow, which is still better than making 1d8+DEX + 6d6 from sneak attack as a pure 12 level Rogue, and gives you better chances to hit. It will also be better damage output than a pure 12-level Fighter can achieve with their 2 extra attacks.

It should be noted that the wording is once per turn, not once per round. In comparison to Extra Attack feature, the Sneak Atatck can also be used out of your turn. Which means that Sneak Attack could be used for Opportunity Attacks, and possibly as a Reaction Attack (Such as the recipient of the Battle Master Maneuver: Commander's Strike, thanks @MivaScott for this catch)

Comment: It should be noted that the wording is once _per turn_, not once _per round_. Which means that Sneak Attack could also be used for Opportunity Attacks, and possibly as a Reaction Attack (Such as the recipient of the Battle Master Maneuver:
Commander's Strike)

Comment: If once per turn, and I used it for my attack, that means i would not be able to use it as a reaction then?

Comment: @J.Wagner: Reactions usually occur on other characters' turns, so you would be able to use it again then (assuming you still meet all the Sneak Attack requirements).

Comment: Also note that since you get multiple attacks you have more chances of landing a hit to trigger sneak attack off.