# Rogue Sneak Attack with Dual-Wield

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack

I am aware that this question is quite similar to another posed on this site, but I specifically need to understand whether you *declare* you are using the Sneak Attack on a given attack or whether it just happens on its own.  As a related matter, let's say my rogue is dual-wielding and chooses Sneak Attack on the first attack (main hand). If the main hand misses, has he "wasted" his one Sneak Attack attempt or does that then roll over to the off-hand attack?  If the latter, is the implication that the Sneak Attack damage just "happens" whenever you get your first successful hit (which would then have implications for rounds with multiple main attacks)?  Thanks all!

Comment: If this is about 5e, does this answer you question? [If I have Extra Attacks, when can I decide which one is a sneak attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117613/if-i-have-extra-attacks-when-can-i-decide-which-one-is-a-sneak-attack)

Comment: As a former technical writer, I really appreciate the attention to detail and diligence to help curate the questions and answers, to make sure they are as effective and efficient as possible!

Comment: @mike Does the question that GcL mentioned answer your own?

Comment: GcL answered all of my questions in one fell swoop - thank you all!